# Construct a set by using the union of intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem? I think for about a day.... but no clue.]

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem? I think for about a day.... but no clue.

Comment: Since the problem lists countable sequences of intervals: Do you know that $\mathbb Q$ is countable? Can you think of a way of splitting $1$ into infinitely many positive numbers $c_1,c_2,\dots$: $1=c_1+c_2+\dots$? Do you see how to approach the problem now?

Answer (score 1):

The rationals are countable.  Around each one, put an interval, with the sum of the lengths of the intervals being $1$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what "construct" a set means.... I think I should use [p-ep,p+ep] as an interval,then the sum of the length is less than 1. But how should I check the second property, and how should I construct a set then? Thank you!!

Comment: To construct a set, in this case, is to list a countably infinite set of intervals, just like the first line of the problem.  If each interval is open, the union will be open-can you see why?  You need to choose the lengths so they sum to less than $1$.  Saying each one is $\epsilon$ is not sufficient.

Comment: I think I should construct like this: [p-ep,p+ep]U[p-ep/2,p+ep/2][p-ep/4,p+ep/4]U[p-ep/8,p+ep/8]. Then the interval is 2ep+ep+ep/2+ep/4+....less than 4ep. Because ep can be sufficiently small, it's less than 1. But I am still wondering how can I use this to prove Q C S? Can I say P is arbitrary rational number so Q C S? Thanks!

Comment: You need to center each interval on a rational.  Since the rationals are countable, you have enough intervals to do it.  Then every rational is in $S$